# > Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE Warning: Failed to parse host error in android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, xml

i was just trying to use the firebase auth dependency but it is showing this error in my whatsapp clone app

But when i try to sync the project the following error comes as shown in the image : that is

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Warning: Failed to parse host dhruv

All the codes are provided below

[`Image of the gradle error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcxKx.png)

Here is the build.gradle(module level) file

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsappclone"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'


    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Here is the build.gradle(Project level)

```html
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the settings.gradle

```html
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "WhatsappClone"
include ':app'
```

My signup activity

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.whatsappclone.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        getSupportActionBar().hide();


    }
}
```

Please help.